# MassTransit Transactional Outbox Delay Handling

Tags: .net, masstransit

When publishing to the MassTransit Inbox is there a way to define that the handling of the outbox should be delayed?
I.e. not the message being sent over the bus, but the inbox/outbox context being handled by with a TimeSpan delay?
I guess it would need to be in the message being published that the handling should be delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delay the delivery/consumption of a message, the producer should delay it when the message is produced.